# AngularJS switch controller based on variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I want to do something similar to a $routeProvider .when but instead of using URL I would like to load an HTML file and a new controller based on a variable change.

Assume I use a $http polling and the poll has a variable that changes, and I would like to change the Controller and template based on that. What is the best strategy for this

I'm new to this so please excuse if this is a stupid question.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is you could do something like this

```
<div>
  <directive1 ng-if="switch_var == val_1"></directive1>
  <directive2 ng-if="switch_var == val_2"></directive2>
  ...
</div>
```

Create a directive for each template/controller combo you want, and then choose which directive to show based on your poll variable.

Alternative to using a bunch of ng-if's, use ng-switch - http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch

Comment: What I have done now is editing the $location.url and when that changes I use $routeProvider to change controllers and templates. Any comment to that? Seems to be working right now.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question. It seems to me as though you are using ngRoute as it's intended. Are you changing $location.url based on your "poll variable"? If so, it sounds as though you're simulating the user clicking a link. I'd say that's fine. However, users can press the back button and go back to the previous template/controller. Maybe this is what you want, maybe not.

Comment: right, but I do not want the user to be going back and I don't really want the URL to change either. I am just trying to keep the code clean and use a controller for each of the pages. I am not too familiar with Angular so using separate controller might just be me misunderstanding but I like the idea of initializing code from a given page. Thank you for answering. I might go the directive way. :-)

Comment: If you don't want the URL to change, the only way I can think of how to do is the directive way. (I am not an AngularJS expert, though) You can pair up a template and controller to a single directive, much like pairing a template and controller to a URL route. Then, using ng-if/ng-switch and switching between directives will switch you between controllers/templates without changing the page's URL. Here's a quick example http://plnkr.co/edit/vjAc96SeqEWwL06Gr4QN

Comment: Fantastic. I was hoping to avoid the switch on the front, but it is better than the url change. I really appreciate you bouncing this off with me!!!

Comment: No problem. Just make sure to come back to StackOverflow one day when you're an Angular wiz and share your knowledge. :)